# Upgrade to MariaDB 10 from MariaDB 5.5 via yum fails

Tags: mysql, mariadb, upgrade, mariadb-10.4

I want to upgrade mariadb from 5.5... to 10. But when I run "yum update -y", screen show like below:

```
Upgrading directly from MySQL <unrecognized version package MariaDB-server-5.5.36-1.el6.x86_64
MariaDB-server-5.5.36-1.el6.x86_64 is not installed> to MariaDB 10.0 may not
be safe in all cases.  A manual dump and restore using mysqldump is
recommended.  It is important to review the MariaDB manual's Upgrading
section for version-specific incompatibilities.

A manual upgrade is required.

- Ensure that you have a complete, working backup of your data and my.cnf
  files
- Shut down the MySQL server cleanly
- Remove the existing MySQL packages.  Usually this command will
  list the packages you should remove:
  rpm -qa | grep -i '^mysql-'

  You may choose to use 'rpm --nodeps -ev <package-name>' to remove
  the package which contains the mysqlclient shared library.  The
  library will be reinstalled by the MariaDB-shared package.
- Install the new MariaDB packages supplied by Monty Program AB
- Ensure that the MariaDB server is started
- Run the 'mysql_upgrade' program
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: *A manual upgrade is required* It already said so.

Comment: @Raptor: yes, but it did not show what I should do step by step for each environment

Answer (score 3):

I fix by myself, I post here for anyone need:

I run,

```
rpm -qa | grep -i '^maria'
```

Screen show:

```
MariaDB-common-10.0.12-1
MariaDB-client-10.0.12-1
MariaDB-server-5.5.38-1
MariaDB-shared-10.0.12-1
```

My "MariaDB-server" is still 5.5, I stop and remove it (backup all before do change anything):

```
yum remove MariaDB-server
```

then install again:

```
yum install MariaDB-server
```

screen:

```
Total size: 56 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing     : MariaDB-server                                                                                                                  1/1

Installed:
  MariaDB-server.i386 0:10.0.12-1
```

run again:

```
rpm -qa | grep -i '^maria'
```

screen show:

```
MariaDB-common-10.0.12-1
MariaDB-client-10.0.12-1
MariaDB-server-10.0.12-1
MariaDB-shared-10.0.12-1
```

It's OK.

Comment: You should add backup data before the removal of 5.5 and restore the data of 10

Comment: have you perform `mysql_upgrade`?

Comment: @Muhaimin Abdul: I did, and according to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/getting-started/upgrading/upgrading-from-mariadb-55-to-mariadb-100/ => we must uninstall 5.5 first

Comment: but you only uninstall the mariadb server and client only right?

Comment: I don't remember, I did it long time ago. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found steps on the official MariaDB website for upgrading to the latest stable version.

1. under /etc/yum.repos.d/ add MariaDB.repo with the following configs:

   > `[mariadb]`
   >   `name = MariaDB`
   >   `baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.2/centos7-amd64`
   >   `gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB`
   >   `gpgcheck=1`
2. Run ***sudo yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client***
   Full steps can be found in this [tutorial](https://kodesmart.com/kode/upgrading-mariadb-5-5-10-2-centos-7)